# Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid

Tags: ssis

I am creating a Excel sheet version 2007 dynamically in SSIS using execute sql task. But I am getting an error.

"verify the column metadata is valid"

Please suggest me any solution!!

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility that you've some column with data types not matching on source and destination. Check that and if there is mismatch use Data conversion Transformation or derived column.